# How can it possible that after implementing Runnable interface in java Thread methods are call?

Tags: java

How can it possible that after implementing Runnable interface in java Thread methods are call?

Comment: @spkothale: Please edit your question and provide more information about what you try to do.

Comment: ain't making no damn sense to me :)

Comment: @Suraj: You know, that's the very first swearword I've seen on SO in my five months here.

Comment: @crowder..thanks...what can i say...i have been told before not to do SO after drinking...

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to read up on basic threads. Check out [this page](http://oreilly.com/catalog/expjava/excerpt/index.html), specifically look at the example under the heading "Creating and starting threads"

Answer (score 1):

Are you passing your `Runnable` implementation to the `Thread` constructor?

This is the recommended way to create and start a thread:

```
class MyRunnable implements Runnable {
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Hello, World!");
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Thread thread = new Thread(new MyRunnable());
        thread.start();
    }
}
```

Is this similar to how you are attempting it?

Some common gotchas with Java threads:

- Calling `thread.run()` instead of `thread.start()`
- Calling a static method through an instance, e.g. `thread.sleep(1000)` makes the *current* thread sleep, not the target thread.

Answer (score 1):

I'm presuming that you are having this question because when Runnable interface is implemented what is provided is implementation for method `run()`.
And we don't make any explicit invocation of `run` method to start the Thread.

In the below exmaple (from [Java tutorial](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/essential/concurrency/runthread.html)) the Thread is started by invoking the `start()` method:

```
public class HelloRunnable implements Runnable {

    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Hello from a thread!");
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        (new Thread(new HelloRunnable())).start();
    }

}
```

And if you look at javadoc for the method 'start()` of Thread class
in the JAVA API, this is what it says:

**start**
*public void start()*

Causes this thread to begin execution; the Java Virtual Machine calls the **run** method of this thread. 
The result is that two threads are running concurrently: the current thread (which returns from the call to the start method) and the other thread (which executes its run method).

Answer (score 0):

At any time, from anywhere, you can call [`Thread.currentThread()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#currentThread()) to get a reference to the currently-running thread, if that helps. If you need to override methods from the `Thread` class, you'll need to inherit from it rather than implementing `Runnable`, but there's not usually a good reason to do that.

Answer (score 0):

It is made possible by using Thread class constructor .otherwise it is not possible at all.

```
class ImplementsRunnable implements Runnable {
public void run() {
 System.out.println("ImplementsRunnable");
 }
 } 
public class DemoRunnable {
  public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
             ImplementsRunnable rc = new ImplementsRunnable();
             Thread t1 = new Thread(rc); 
             t1.start();
  /*here with the help of Constructor of Thread Class we call start method which is not in ImplementsRunnable*/
}
}
```